# How to get md5 of multiple images in short time?

Tags: java, android, hash, io, md5-file

In my app, i am generating md5 of about 3000 images having size up to 700 MB.
I already have Arraylist of file paths of images.

The problem is time consumption which is up to 55 seconds. I want to reduce it up to least time, taken up to 8 to 12 seconds at least if possible or even less.

This is the algorithm for generating md5

```
  public static String getMd5OfFile(String filePath)
{
    String returnVal = "";
    try
    {
        InputStream input   = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[15360];     
      //byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      // byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        MessageDigest md5Hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        int           numRead = 0;
        while (numRead != -1)
        {
            numRead = input.read(buffer);
            if (numRead > 0)
            {
                md5Hash.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
        }
        input.close();

        byte [] md5Bytes = md5Hash.digest();
        for (int i=0; i < md5Bytes.length; i++)
        {
            returnVal += Integer.toString( ( md5Bytes[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}
    return returnVal.toUpperCase();
}
```

map is taking String as key, value as Arraylist

```
HashMap<String,Arraylist<String>> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

This is algorithm for finding same md5 duplicate files

```
 void Duplicatefinder(ArrayList<String> filepaths)
{

    HashMap<String,String> checkmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String filepath : filepaths)
    {

        String md5 = getMd5OfFile(filepath);
     if(checkmap.containsKey(md5)) {
         if (!map.containsKey(md5)) {
             map.put(md5, new ArrayList<String>());
             String original = checkmap.get(md5);
             ArrayList<String> list = map.get(md5);
             list.add(original);
             map.put(md5,list);
         }
         ArrayList<String> list = map.get(md5);
         list.add(filepath);
         map.put(md5, list);
     }
     else {
         checkmap.put(md5,filepath);
     }

    }
}
```

calling Duplicate finder in Async task,s do in background and showing loading animation to user while all md5 of files are taken and displayed in recycler view.

Comment: you are generating those md5 sums every time your app starts? no caching results and generating only if some files change / are added?

Comment: yes but on first time user experience it will take time, can it be made much more faster. a little explanation with code please.

Comment: 3000 images of 700 MB each?? Just reading that from disk is going to take a while. Did you *profile* the code to see where the performance bottleneck is?

Comment: calling duplicate function in Async do in background which is separate to UI thread,so in my view it is similar to separate thread.

Comment: total 700 MB of 3000 images.(not each)

Comment: Do you have images large than 15360 bytes? If so try making the `input` buffer larger than the largest image though I don't think it will help much. Your code is fine, not everything can be made faster.

Comment: no i was changing bytes range to check if some percent of time reduction could happen.Can it be possible instead of  reading full file just read least kb to generate md5 of files, if so provide an example.Largest images are up to 2MB and most are up to 200 KB to 500 KB

Comment: Why do you need md5? If it's only to find duplicates you can use [Adler32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Adler32.html) It should be much faster.

Comment: also what is the distribution of your files in terms of size? note that only the files with the same size can be the same (diplicated)

Comment: but different files with same size can be there too,and files are random as i am getting paths from android external storage.

Comment: but you dont have to generate md5 sums for files of size 700,000,000 and 699,999,999 bytes because you know they are different

Comment: ok thats a good suggestion i will implement that, but in my scenario about 90% files are duplicate.